# UIViewController setView nil automatically removes from superview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Calling setView on a UIViewController removes the current view from its superview automatically.  I couldn't find this documented. In my case I want to dynamically swap a UIViewController object for another while maintaining my view structure. I was planning to just relink the view to the new controller but alas, that doesn't work.

In general, automatically removing the view from its superview seems like a sensible decision.  The documentation should reflect this though.

(For anyone thinking it's a really bad idea to swap a view controller object in this way, let me add that the controller I'm swapping in is a subclass of the existing controller.  And this method is great for adding functionality to a view that is an extension of another.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
UIView *viewToKeep = self.viewController.view;
UIView *superview = viewToKeep.superview;
self.viewController.view = nil;  // removes the view from its superview

UIViewController *swapInViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
swapInViewController.view = viewToKeep;
[superview addSubview: viewToKeep];
[viewToKeep applyConstraintsToFillSuperview];  // a helper to add auto layout constraints that make the view always fill it's parent
self.viewController = swapInViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is definitely going against the grain in UIKit, and therefore very likely a bad idea.

That said, here's something which prevents the view from being automatically removed, which means you don't need to use `addSubview` to put it back where it was.

Only tested as far as you see below, caveat emptor, etc. In Swift:

```swift
class View: UIView {
    var preventRemovalFromSuperView = false
    override func removeFromSuperview() {
        if !preventRemovalFromSuperView {
            super.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        preventRemovalFromSuperView = false
    }
}

let vc1 = UIViewController()
let vc2 = UIViewController()
let sv = UIView()
let v = View()

// Existing hierarchy
sv.addSubview(v)
vc1.view = v

// Swap view controllers
v.preventRemovalFromSuperView = true // Prevent automatic removal
vc1.view = nil // Prevent UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exception
vc2.view = v

// Check that view was not automatically removed
v.isDescendantOfView(sv) // true
```